# Email validation - What is wrong with my regex code?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to validate an email address using preg_match..

But i'm getting this error..

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '+'

This is my code

```
preg_match("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", $email, $matches);
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my regex?

Thanks

Comment: I'd strongly recommend not writing this code yourself. https://code.google.com/p/php-email-address-validation/source/browse/trunk/EmailAddressValidator.php

Comment: even `space` is a valid char in email..point is don't use regex to parse email..put it as simple as this `.*@.*` that's it

Comment: You can be more restrictive on the right side of the `@`, which has to be a valid domain name, but yeah, pretty much anything goes on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put delimiters around the regex when you use `preg_match`.  The standard is `/`.  If you use the delimiter in the expression, you have to escape it.

```
preg_match("/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/", $email, $matches);
```

You could also consider using

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: Also, these expressions `(?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?` are a little odd. Presumably they could be replaced with `[a-z0-9-]*?` for simplicity.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I would think that it should be `[a-z0-9-]+?` :)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I don't think so, as `+` requires at least one wheres the construction in a non capturing group followed by a `?` which means that it is optional (required zero or one time) - so the expression is saying `[a-z0-9-]` zero or more times (i.e. a `*`). On second thoughts i'm not even sure the `?` is required - the expression can be greedy.